# How do I resolve the ` /packages cannot be represented as URI` issue?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have just started on Coursera's Functional Programming with Scala and I find it hard to submit my assignment. I can individually run my functions in my IntelliJ IDE but when I go into the terminal and type `sbt about` I'm presented with this error:

I'm on MacOS

Is there something really wrong with my setup?

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/anallana/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-14.0.1/Contents/Home
$ pwd
path/to/project
$ sbt about
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/anallana/.sbt/1.0/plugins
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[error] java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
[error]         at java.base/jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtPath.toUri(JrtPath.java:176)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.JrtClassPath.asURLs(DirectoryClassPath.scala:204)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.$anonfun$asURLs$1(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70)
[error]         at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:240)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:237)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.classpath.AggregateClassPath.asURLs(AggregateClassPath.scala:55)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader(Macros.scala:66)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.findMacroClassLoader$(Macros.scala:65)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.findMacroClassLoader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$defaultMacroClassloaderCache$2(MacroRuntimes.scala:56)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable$perRunCaches$$anon$1.apply(SymbolTable.scala:457)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.defaultMacroClassloader$(MacroRuntimes.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.defaultMacroClassloader(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes$MacroRuntimeResolver.resolveRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:76)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.$anonfun$standardMacroRuntime$3(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:206)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike.getOrElseUpdate$(MapLike.scala:203)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:38)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.standardMacroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:31)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:448)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$14.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroRuntime$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:445)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.reflect.macros.runtime.MacroRuntimes.macroRuntime$(MacroRuntimes.scala:25)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroRuntime(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.$anonfun$expand$1(Macros.scala:619)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global.withInfoLevel(Global.scala:219)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.expand(Macros.scala:613)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros$MacroExpander.apply(Macros.scala:600)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand(Macros.scala:764)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.standardMacroExpand$(Macros.scala:762)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.standardMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:432)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins$$anon$12.default(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.invoke(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:401)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.AnalyzerPlugins.pluginsMacroExpand$(AnalyzerPlugins.scala:429)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.pluginsMacroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Macros.macroExpand$(Macros.scala:757)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$$anon$1.macroExpand(Global.scala:469)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.vanillaAdapt$1(Typers.scala:1163)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1223)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5631)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$adapt$2(Typers.scala:844)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.silent(Typers.scala:693)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$adapt$1(Typers.scala:841)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adaptToImplicitMethod$1(Typers.scala:471)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.adapt(Typers.scala:1219)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5631)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:5833)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5536)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1999)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedModuleDef(Typers.scala:1868)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5538)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStat$1(Typers.scala:5681)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.$anonfun$typedStats$10(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3264)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5247)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5540)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5617)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.apply(Analyzer.scala:106)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:441)
[error]         at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Analyzer$typerFactory$TyperPhase.run(Analyzer.scala:96)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.$anonfun$compileAndLoad$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]         at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compile$1(Eval.scala:248)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.scala:253)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:218)
[error]         at sbt.compiler.Eval.eval(Eval.scala:128)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDslEntry(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:239)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.$anonfun$evaluateSbtFile$2(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:158)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:388)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:294)
[error]         at sbt.internal.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:156)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1136)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$2(Load.scala:1144)
[error]         at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:127)
[error]         at scala.collection.MapLike.getOrElse$(MapLike.scala:125)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:1143)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$discoverProjects$4(Load.scala:1151)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:58)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:51)
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226)
[error]         at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:1151)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:1165)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:862)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:937)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:726)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$11(Load.scala:729)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:729)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:1312)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:1242)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:1225)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$2(Load.scala:694)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$loadUnit$1(Load.scala:694)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:688)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$builtinLoader$4(Load.scala:484)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader$.$anonfun$componentLoader$5(BuildLoader.scala:176)
[error]         at sbt.internal.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:241)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:546)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:562)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:492)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:471)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:251)
[error]         at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
[error]         at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
[error]         at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
[error]         at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
[error]         at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
[error]         at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
[error]         at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI
...
```

Comment: I would suggest you using **Java 8** or **Java 11** instead of **Java 14**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why is Java 8 or 11 better?

Comment: @Cit5 because those are more stable and well-tested versions: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I opened a project that still had an old version of sbt (≤1.2.0) with a new version of Java (JDK 17). Upgrading to a new [version of sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) (e.g. setting `sbt.version=1.6.2` in `project/build.properties`) fixed it.