# Compiling Scala 2.12.16 with Gradle and Java 17 getting java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI

Tags: java, scala, gradle, sbt

I have a scala project that is stuck on version 2.12. I am trying to upgrade the Java version to 17, but am getting the infamous `java.io.IOError: java.lang.RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI` error. I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60308229/scala-packages-cannot-be-represented-as-uri) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63800811/how-do-i-resolve-the-packages-cannot-be-represented-as-uri-issue) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73428839/packages-cannot-be-represented-as-uri) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66976989/sbt-test-error-java-lang-runtimeexception-packages-cannot-be-represented-as-u) (all SO Q&A's) but all to no avail. The common advice between all those answers is either to use Java 8 (not what I want), to upgrade Scala to the latest patch version (already did that) or to upgrade SBT. Regarding the last point, I added the following snippet to my `build.gradle.kts` file but am still getting the error:

```
scala {
    zincVersion.set("1.8.0")
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it work for you with java 8? I mean, if you will have worked solution, it will be easy to migrate to new java. Why not you use SBT (1.6.0+ version)? If you use sbt, can you provide minimum reproducible example?

Comment: it works fine with java 8 and java 11, only java 17 is giving me trouble.

Comment: @Jewels Do you have any updates? Do you have reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

Please double check that you're using Scala 2.12.15+, the latest is 2.12.17.

`packages cannot be represented as URI` was a bug in Scala compiler and Gradle Scala plugin uses Scala compiler (sbt zinc compiler)

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11794 *Scala 2.13.0 OpenJdk 13: REPL crashes with RuntimeException: /packages cannot be represented as URI*

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11762 *Failed to run scala on Eclipse OpenJ9 VM, Java 13*

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11608 *Compiler crashes when using macros in Scala 2.12 with JDK 13*

https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11381#issuecomment-539727339 *GlobalSymbolLoaders#lookupMemberAtTyperPhaseIfPossible throw NullPointerException with JDK12*

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

**Version compatibility table**

| JDK version | Minimum Scala versions |
| --- | --- |
| 20 | 3.3.0 (soon), 2.13.11 (soon), 2.12.18 (soon) |
| 19 | 3.2.0, 2.13.9, 2.12.16 |
| 18 | 3.1.3, 2.13.7, 2.12.15 |
| **17** (LTS) | 3.0.0, 2.13.6, **2.12.15** |
| 11 (LTS) | 3.0.0, 2.13.0, 2.12.4, 2.11.12 |
| 8 (LTS) | 3.0.0, 2.13.0, 2.12.0, 2.11.0 |

Zinc 1.8.0 uses Scala 2.12.17.

https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/v1.8.0/project/Dependencies.scala#L10

```
val scala210 = "2.10.7"
val scala211 = "2.11.12"
val scala212 = "2.12.17"
val scala213 = "2.13.8"
```

The issue *Update Zinc used by Scala plugin to 1.7.1* https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/21392 is still open, the pull request *Update Zinc used by Scala plugin to 1.7.1* https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/21393 was closed without merging. So Gradle 8.1.0 seems to be still on `zinc_2.13:1.6.1`

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/v8.1.0/subprojects/scala/build.gradle.kts#L32

```
compileOnly("org.scala-sbt:zinc_2.13:1.6.1") {
  ...
```

And zinc 1.6.1 is on Scala 2.13.6

https://github.com/sbt/zinc/blob/v1.6.1/project/Dependencies.scala#L11

```
val scala210 = "2.10.7"
val scala211 = "2.11.12"
val scala212 = "2.12.15"
val scala213 = "2.13.6"
```

where `packages cannot be represented as URI` was supposed to be fixed.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html#sec:configure_zinc_compiler

**Zinc compatibility table**

| Gradle version | Supported Zinc versions | Zinc coordinates | Required Scala version | Supported Scala compilation version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7.5 and newer | [SBT Zinc.](https://github.com/sbt/zinc) Versions 1.6.0 and above. | org.scala-sbt:zinc_2.13 | Scala 2.13.x is required for *running* Zinc. | Scala 2.10.x through 3.x can be compiled. |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

Scala 2.12.15+, 2.13.6+ are considered to be compatible with Java 17. So if there are still incompatibilities maybe you should open an issue at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues, https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues or https://github.com/scala/bug/

---

Actually, I can't reproduce `packages cannot be represented as URI` with Gradle 8.1, Scala 2.12.17, zinc 1.8.0, Java eclipse_adoptium-17-amd64-linux/jdk-17.0.7+7

https://github.com/DmytroMitin/gradledemo

*settings.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version "0.4.0"
}

rootProject.name = "gradledemo"
include("app")
```

*app/build.gradle.kts*

```kotlin
plugins {
    scala

    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.17")

    implementation("com.chuusai:shapeless_2.12:2.3.10")
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}

scala {
    zincVersion.set("1.8.0")
}

// see (*)
// Without -target or -release: Task :app:compileScala FAILED: jvm-1.17 is not a valid choice for -target, bad option: -target:jvm-1.17
// With -target: [Warn] : -target is deprecated: Scala 2.12 cannot emit valid class files for targets newer than 8 (this is possible with Scala 2.13). Use -release to compile against a specific platform API version.
tasks.withType<ScalaCompile>() {
    targetCompatibility = ""
    scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = listOf("-release:17")
}

application {
    mainClass.set("gradledemo.App")
}
```

*app/src/main/scala/gradledemo/App.scala*

```scala
package gradledemo

import shapeless._

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(1 :: "a" :: true :: HNil)
  }
}
```

```
$ gradle clean

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 533ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed

$ gradle run

> Task :app:run
1 :: a :: true :: HNil

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 4s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

How to reproduce `packages cannot be represented as URI`? Please prepare reproduction.

(*) [Scala build error on Java 11 using intellijidea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878493/scala-build-error-on-java-11-using-intellijidea)